# Pivot and aggregate 1..n duplicate records Postgres psql

Tags: postgresql, pivot, psql

I have a table `tbl_action` like this:

| game_id | action | action_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | start | 2022-04-05T10:30+00 |
| 1 | attack | 2022-04-05T10:45+00 |
| 1 | defend | 2022-04-05T11:30+00 |
| 1 | attack | 2022-04-05T11:45+00 |
| 1 | defend | 2022-04-05T12:00+00 |
| 1 | stop | 2022-04-05T12:10+00 |

```
create table if not exists tblaction;

insert into "tblaction" (game_id, action_name, action_time) values (1,'start','2022-04-05T10:30+00'),
(2,'attack','2022-04-05T10:45+00'),
(3,'defend','2022-04-05T11:30+00'),
(4,'attack','2022-04-05T11:45+00'),
(5,'defend','2022-04-05T12:00+00'),
(6,'stop','2022-04-05T12:10+00');
```

I want to pivot it like this:

| game_id | start | attack1 | defend1 | ... | attackn | defendn | stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-05T10:30+00 | 2022-04-05T10:45+00 | 2022-04-05T11:30+00 | ... | 2022-04-05T11:45+00 | 2022-04-05T12:00+00 | 2022-04-05T12:10+00 |

My question is how to aggregate actions 1..n instead of aggregating all of each unique action_name into one number. I am using Postgres.

This MySQL sample code works when each action_name occurs <2 times but I would like something that works 1..n. I don't want to remove the duplicates. I am not limited to MySQL I can use the latest versions of Postgres.

```
SELECT

 game_id, 

MAX( CASE WHEN action_name = 'start' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "start",

MIN( CASE WHEN action_name = 'attack' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "attack",

MIN( CASE WHEN action_name = 'defend' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "defend",

MAX( CASE WHEN action_name = 'attack' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "attack",

MAX( CASE WHEN action_name = 'defend' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "defend",

MAX( CASE WHEN action_name = 'stop' THEN action_time ELSE NULL END ) AS "stop"

FROM

 tblaction

GROUP BY

 game_id

ORDER BY

 game_id ASC;
```

I read the Postgres tablefunc docs and tried \crosstabview in pgadmin4 and get the error `\crosstabview: query result contains multiple data values for row "1", column "attack"`

```
SELECT game_id, action_name, action_time FROM tblaction \crosstabview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery with `ROW_NUMER` window function which help you make row number by `game_id`, `action_name` columns, then you can use condition aggregate function for that `rn`

```
SELECT
    game_id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'start'  THEN action_time   END ) AS "start",
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'attack' AND rn = 1 THEN action_time  END ) AS "attack1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'defend' AND rn = 1 THEN action_time  END ) AS "defend1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'attack' AND rn = 2 THEN action_time  END ) AS "attack",
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'defend' AND rn = 2 THEN action_time  END ) AS "defend",
    MAX(CASE WHEN action_name = 'stop'   THEN action_time   END ) AS "stop"
FROM
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY game_id,action_name ORDER BY action_time) rn
    FROM tblaction
) t1
GROUP BY
 game_id
ORDER BY
 game_id ASC;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6917d11dd7a50c31ba643456ff292700)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that it will be simpler and more flexible with GROUP_CONCAT.
NB The question said to work on mySQL or Postgres. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8719aedb7ab5736caf79fe86e76d6f40 for a version for Postgres using `STRING_AGG( ~ ,',')` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`, otherwise identical

> ```
> create table tblaction (
> game_id int, 
> action_name varchar(20), 
> action_time varchar(25)
> );
>
> insert into tblaction 
> (game_id, action_name, action_time) values 
> (1,'start','2022-04-05T10:30+00'),
> (1,'attack','2022-04-05T10:45+00'),
> (1,'defend','2022-04-05T11:30+00'),
> (1,'attack','2022-04-05T11:45+00'),
> (1,'defend','2022-04-05T12:00+00'),
> (1,'stop','2022-04-05T12:10+00');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   game_id,
>   GROUP_CONCAT(case when action_name='start' then action_time end) start,
>   GROUP_CONCAT(case when action_name='stop' then action_time  end) stop,
>   COUNT(action_time) "number",
>   GROUP_CONCAT(case when action_name='attack' then action_time  end) "attacks",
>   GROUP_CONCAT(case when action_name='defend' then action_time  end) "defends"
> FROM tblaction
> GROUP BY
>   game_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> game_id | start               | stop                | number | attacks                                 | defends                                
> ------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----: | :-------------------------------------- | :--------------------------------------
>       1 | 2022-04-05T10:30+00 | 2022-04-05T12:10+00 |      6 | 2022-04-05T10:45+00,2022-04-05T11:45+00 | 2022-04-05T11:30+00,2022-04-05T12:00+00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6feace2da8714d68195409dd4fb3512a)*

Comment: works with MySQL 5.7, does not work with PSQL 13, error I get is: `syntax error at or near "start"`

Comment: Ok the question says mySQL or Postgres. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8719aedb7ab5736caf79fe86e76d6f40 for version Postgres using STRING_AGG